# How to make kubernetes docker secret work?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Data showing "xxx" has been masked.

Problem description:

Success Scenario:  When i make my image public in docker registry, my pod is getting created successfully.

Failure Scenario: When i make my image private in docker registry. My image pull fails on kubernetes cluster.

Please details below and help.

I have my image published to docker registry.

Following is my kubernetes secret:

```
c:\xxxxxxx\temp>kubectl get secret regcredx -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: xxxxxx
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-25T21:38:18Z
  name: regcredx
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1174545"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/regcredx
  uid: 49a71ba5-d89e-11e8-8bd2-005056b7126c
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Here is my pod.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: whatever
spec:
  containers:
    - name: whatever
      image: xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx:123
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcredx
```

Here is my pod config in cluster:

```
c:\Sharief\temp>kubectl get pod whatever -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 100.96.1.81/32
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-26T20:49:11Z
  name: whatever
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1302024"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/whatever
  uid: 9783b81f-d960-11e8-94ca-005056b7126c
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - tail -f /dev/null
    image: xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: whatever
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-4db4c
      readOnly: true
   dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcredx
  nodeName: xxxx-pvt
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-4db4c
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-4db4c
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-10-26T20:49:33Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-10-26T20:49:33Z
    message: 'containers with unready status: [whatever]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-10-26T20:49:11Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - image: xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: whatever
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
        message: Back-off pulling image "xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123"
        reason: ImagePullBackOff
  hostIP: xx.xxx.xx.xx
  phase: Pending
  podIP: xx.xx.xx.xx
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: 2018-10-26T20:49:33Z
```

Here is my pod discription:

```
c:\xxxxxxx\temp>kubectl describe pod whatever
Name:               whatever
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt/xx.xx.xx.xx
Start Time:         Fri, 26 Oct 2018 15:49:33 -0500
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:        cni.projectcalico.org/podIP=xxx.xx.xx.xx/xx
Status:             Pending
IP:                 xxx.xx.x.xx
Containers:
  whatever:
    Container ID:
    Image:         xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      tail -f /dev/null
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4db4c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-4db4c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4db4c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                 From                                Message
  ----     ------                 ----                ----                                -------
  Normal   Scheduled              27m                 default-scheduler                   Successfully assigned whatever to xxx
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  26m                 kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-4db4c"
  Normal   Pulling                25m (x4 over 26m)   kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  pulling image "xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123"
  Warning  Failed                 25m (x4 over 26m)   kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  Failed to pull image "xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx not found: does not exist or no pull access
  Warning  Failed                 25m (x4 over 26m)   kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                16m (x41 over 26m)  kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  Back-off pulling image "xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:123"
  Warning  Failed                 1m (x106 over 26m)  kubelet, co2-vmkubwrk01company-pvt  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the format of the data within the secret. Different registries require different formats, depending on how you're trying to authenticate, so worth checking to make sure. If you created the secret using the `kubectl create secret docker-registry` command, also worth making sure the credentials you supplied were correct.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes could not find your repository ,  the image path is wrong , you need to fix this:

```
image: xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx:123
```

One thing you can try to test the assumption that pre-pull the image on the node on which the deployment is going to happen. do `docker images` , note the correct uri/repo:tag and update it in you deployment.